# Сохранение категорий в exel пайтон

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

Всем привет! не могу найти решение как исправить ошибку in start_cacao exel["название"] = n

ошибка появляется ,когда пытаюсь сохранить 2 разные категории в один файл Exel. По отдельности в разные файлы exel запись идет без проблем.

```
import pandas as pd
exel=pd.DataFrame()
n,p,u,x,s,f,k=[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

def start_cacao():#Категория Какао

global exel
count = 1
while True:
  sleep(2)
  link3=f"https://online.metro-cc.ru/category/chaj-kofe-kakao/kakao-kofejnye-napitki?page={count}" 
  headers={"User-Agent": ua.chrome}
  response=requests.get(link3,headers=headers).text
  bs=BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

name_cacao=bs.find_all("span", class_="product-card-name__text")
for name in zip(name_cacao):
     n.append(name.getText())
exel["название"] = n
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("./Парсинг_Какао.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter',engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}})
exel.to_excel(writer,index=False)
writer.close()

def start_cikori():#Категория Цикорий

count = 1
while True:
  sleep(2)
  link2=f"https://online.metro-cc.ru/category/chaj-kofe-kakao/cikorij-kofezameniteli?page={count}" 
  headers={"User-Agent": ua.chrome}
  response=requests.get(link2,headers=headers).text
  bs=BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

  name_cikori=bs.find_all("span", class_="product-card-name__text")
  for name,url in zip(name_cikori):
     n.append(name.getText())
  exel["название"] = n
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter("./Парсинг_Цикорий и кофезаменители.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter',engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}})
 exel.to_excel(writer,index=False)
 writer.close()

def all_tovar():#Сохранить две категории в один exel файл, ошибка возникает тут
 global exel
 start_cikori()
 start_cacao()
 print("Завершен!")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("./Парсинг_Всех_Товаров.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter', engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}})
exel.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.close()
```

Comment: Во-первых исправьте табуляции в коде. Во-вторых ошибка должна быть полностью в вопросе, весь стек-трейс.

Comment: Копировался возможно код через телефон, ошибки у меня нет в табуляции , мне нужна подсказка def all_tovar() ,

Comment: не важно откуда у вас что копировалось - в вопросе неверная табуляция кода. приведите ее в порядок.

Comment: Тему можно закрыть... Вопрос решил все работает